# terraform default_tags block not setting tags in aws resources

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to set default tags to all resources created via terraform script. Default_tag block is added to main.tf file in root module.

All AWS resources are deployed correctly as per script but none of them has tags defined in default section.

```
provider "aws" {
  region = var.aws_region
  default_tags {
    tags = {
        owner = "some_owner"
        service = "some_service"
        environment = var.environment
    }
  }
}
```

did I missed anything here? Please advise.

Comment: "All AWS resources " - which resource exactly? Where is the rest of the code with those resources?

Comment: Your provider block looks fine. Are you using any other provider alias for AWS that maybe dont define the tags, or are you calling modules that have defined their own provider block?

Comment: @ChrisDoyle I have provider block in each module.

Comment: @ChrisDoyle I have provider block in each module contains region, no tags at module level. But you are right, provider block at module level was blocking default tags. I have removed it and it worked as expected. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed provider block at module level. Here is example of vpc module.

```
# provider "aws" {region = var.aws_region}
```